# How to fix EOF error when reading user input in python 3?

Tags: python, input, eof

I need to read multiple lines from user input, parse them as commands and call functions. I keep getting EOFError even after I have threw an exception. Same thing happens if I put the if..else statements inside 'try'. The program stops at main and wouldn't call the functions.

**EDITED**

```
infile = open('file.csv')
weather = list()
for line in infile:
    parse_one_line() #parse each row into tuples 
                     #and add them into a list

while True:
    try:
        input_stream = input()
        command = input_stream.split()        
    except ValueError:
        pass

    if command == []:
        pass
    elif command[:4] == ['filter', 'TEMP', 'at', 'least']:
        filterRecord()  #user input "filter TEMP at least <integer>"
    elif ...

def filterRecord():  #filter rows that meet 
                    #the criteria into a new list
    global filtered
    filtered = list()
    try:
        for x in range(len(weather)):
           if int(weather[x][2]) >= int(command[-1]):
                 print(weather[x])
                 filtered.append(tuple(weather[x]))
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

Comment: Please give us a complete code snippet that (mostly) runs and tell us the input that yields the error, the desired output, the actual output, and the full traceback for the error. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @RoryDaulton I've added the more code snippet

Comment: Your code is not complete since you have a `elif ...` line, do not show the definition of `parse_one_line()`, and so on. You also have not yet shown the input, desired and actual output, and the traceback.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with this line

```
elif: command == '..'
```

The colon is in the wrong place, change it to

```
elif command == '..':
```

Comment: that's pseudocode, I did use the correct syntax when I ran it